# Problem with Wi-Fi, Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 not showing wireless connection while connected

Tags: drivers, wireless, ethernet, intel, centrino

I m connected to wireless internet but I can`t see any wireless networks and even my wireless connection is shown as ethernet connection. I m  using linux via virtual box and I clearly see that my windows are connected to the wireless. I m new in using linux but I have tried everything (at least I think). I tried to install compat wireless,
I tried this command:

```
# apt update && apt install firmware-iwlwifi
```

and I tried so many things that I`m not even sure what to list. Please help, I m stuck.
If someone needs more information about my problem please ask additional questions about it.

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.

Answer (score 2):

The VM Host should show the Wireless connection.

The VM Guest should show an Wired (ethernet) connection.

That's what the VM application does: The Guest cannot see ANY of the real host hardware. The VM application provides an abstraction layer *that appears to the guest* to be generic hardware with an ethernet connection.

The Guest cannot control the wireless hardware without some exceptional configuration. Controlling the real hardware is the Host's job.